# How to use ecspos-php in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, point-of-sale, thermal-printer

I say thank you before, I hope you can help my problem, this's my first time using framework laravel 5.4 in case of struk printing with windows 7 operating system and using epson U220 which printer connected with USB locally, but when i'm try to access page and click button print, printer doesn't action print page.

**Controller**

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Pembayaran;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Yajra\DataTables\DataTables;
    use Mike42\Escpos\Printer; 
    use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
    use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
    use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\NetworkPrintConnector;

    class PembayaranController extends Controller
    {
        public function print(Request $request)
        {
            try {
                $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("\\wind7\usb\epson");
                $printer = new Escpos($connector);
                $printer -> text("Hello World!\n");
                $printer -> cut();

                $printer -> close();
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                echo "Couldn't print to this printer: " . $e -> getMessage() . "\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

**Route**

```
<?php

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect()->route('home');
});
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::post('/pembayaran/print', 'PembayaranController@print')->name('pembayaran.print');
```

**Blade**

```
<form action="{{ route('pembayaran.print') }}" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" class="form-control" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info">Print</button
</form>
```

Comment: Try using the `share name` of the printer as the `WindowsPrintConnector` argument, something like "epson U220" for instance

Comment: it's good and that working, thank you

Comment: There's a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/charlieuki/receipt-printer) which brings escpos-php into Laravel easier. Check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `share name` should be passed to the `WindowsPrintConnector` as the first argument, instead:

For instance:

```
$connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("epson U220");
```

If the share name was `epson U2020`